# jQuery - Object Expected on IE and $(document).ready(function() {});

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-tools, document-ready

I have a page ([LINK REMOVED]) that works completely well in FireFox and Chrome, but for some reason I am getting an "Object Expected" error in most, if not all versions of IE.

The error occurs on the line

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //^ Error occurs here ^
    ...
}
```

I am using [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html), which implements jQuery 1.4.2, as well as some additional stuff.

I've done some reading around. I've tried to put the ready function at the end of the code, right before the `</body>` tag - in addition, I've tried implementing a timer to let IE load before executing, and I can not shake this error.

Comment: Could you paste the source of the whole page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's quite a bit of code so I provided a link...

Comment: Did you try the $(function() { }) means of document ready?

Comment: @blesh - yes.. I even still have it up at     index2.php

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: "Object Expected" line 768 char 7 code 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one problem that can cause IE to choke where other browsers may not:

```
$('#' + resultDivName).animate({
  height: '300px', // <=== TRAILING COMMA
}, 500, function() {
  // Animation complete.
});
```

Then, in your qtip call, you have:

```
target: 'popPart_WM300BP'
```

I believe [`target` takes a jQuery DOM object](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#elements-target), not a string. DebugBar points to this line as the cause of "object expected".

Finally, it looks like this version of jQuery Tools includes jQuery 1.4.2. Perhaps 1.4.3 or 1.4.4 would be worth a try.

Comment: Wow. I feel like a complete tool. It was the extra commas (it was actually in more than one spot). Thank you very much.

Comment: also, I will look into the target/DOM issue as well. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the url you're using for `jquery.tools`. It is missing the `http:` part.

> //cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js

should be

> http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js

Comment: @Ken - Only if that's the correct path. Looks to me more like OP is attempting to link to the jquerytools cdn.

Comment: I actually have the JS file hosted locally on my web server... what you saw with the long path was an experimentation. I thought maybe the jQuery part was 'getting lost' so I wanted to point to the actual JS file - I apologize and will stop playing around with it. Up-Vote for the catch, though.

Comment: Missing `http:` is fine in itself - http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: @Henrik N: Interesting. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing over a HTTPS connection, check if you are choosing view only the content that was delivered securely. If you choose YES maybe the scripts will not be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$(document).ready` and `$(function(){..}` methods are just fine - in fact when I fired up the Visual Studio debugger and attached to the page, those methods were firing as expected. The problem is that they are trying to call a function named `initializePageMain()` that doesn't exist for some reason. As to why that function doesn't seem to exist... I am not sure.

I would also try "fixing" the script tag that contains this code (sidenote: why isn't doToolTips defined in your index.js file?) to read like the rest of your script tags (get rid of the language element:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>
```

Comment: initializePageMain() is in index.js, and doToolTips() is at the bottom of index.php - just before the $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

This is another gem that causes this error in IE

```
Math..random();
```

Those two dots (..) will ruin you.