# Unable to find an element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am getting an error that says 'object expected' when I am calling a method of an element. I am getting this error even if that element exists on the page.

```
$('#asdf').text();
```

I am calling this in the Onsucceed method of a pagemethod. What may be the reason behind it?

Comment: try $('#asdf').length and see if it selecting anything

Comment: Post all relevant code and markup.

Comment: When are you calling this? After the jQuery script has been referenced and after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: Please have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199577/jquery-object-expected-on-ie-and-document-readyfunction

Comment: I am calling this in Onsucceed method of a pagemethod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you don't have a reference to Jquery?
Try $('#asdf').length and check if it selects anything.
Another possible issue is that you try to select the element before the DOM is ready

```
$(function(){
    $('#asdf').text();
});
```

will occur when the DOM is ready

Answer (score 0):

Could be a few things, in this case it may not be able to find `$('#asdf')` so make sure your id is the same of that of the element on the page.

Check you have imported Jquery correcly as it may not recognise the `$`

finally, make sure your code is running when the page has finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do that before the page finished loading.

Try

```
   jQuery(function($){
     alert($('#asdf').text());
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

What specifically is the 'object' which is being expected? If it is `$` then it means you either haven't included `jquery.js` on your page, or the path to it is incorrect.

If jQuery is included, then you can test if an element exists on the page using:

```
if ($("#asdf").length > 0) {
    alert("asdf esixts");
}
else {
    alert("asdf DOES NOT exist");
}
```

Finally, make sure you are placing your code inside the document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be solved by properly referring to the JQuery file. You may have it in a subdirectory and  path needs to be changed.

Or may be u have a code like ;

```
$("#form1").validate({
        debug: true,
        .....
```

if you have, change false to true

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get this error in IE. This may happen when you had an element with the id of asdf, then you somehow removed it after some ajax call (or replaced it). You could try $("[id=asdf]").text() and see if it fails. If it doesn't, when I am right. 
This is due to the fact that (IMO) IE keeps all elements with ID's in a hash and does not replace the pointer from the hash when the element is replaced.